# How to create a recursive query in BigQuery having the target column as a JSON array?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table called `area_groups` which aims to represent a graph-like association in which there can have recursion.

To illustrate my case, that table has following columns

- `id` (UUID)
- `group_ids` (Array of UUIDs)
- `area_ids` (Array of UUIDs)

This graph will always have `area_ids` as leaves whilst `group_ids` will be nodes/records of `area_groups`.

Exemple:

```
   G1
 /   \
v     v
G2 -> G3
 |    |
 v    v
 A1   A2
```

Above graph would be represented within my database as the `area_groups` table below:

```
+------+--------------+----------+
|  id  |   group_ids  | area_ids |
+------+--------------+----------+
| 'G1' | ['G2', 'G3'] |   NULL   |
+------+--------------+----------+
| 'G2' |    ['G3']    |  ['A1']  |
+------+--------------+----------+
| 'G3' |     NULL     |  ['A2']  |
+------+--------------+----------+
```

My goal is, given a node, get the leaves. Example:

- Given 'G1', get 'A1' and 'A2'
- Given 'G2', get 'A1' and 'A2'
- Given 'G3', get 'A2'

What I have so far is below query, but it's returning only G1.

```
WITH RECURSIVE areas_from_group AS (
  SELECT id, group_ids, area_ids
  FROM area_groups

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    area_groups.id,
    area_groups.group_ids,
    area_groups.area_ids
  FROM areas_from_group, UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(areas_from_group.group_ids)) AS descendent_groups
    JOIN area_groups ON area_groups.id = descendent_groups
)

SELECT *
FROM areas_from_group
WHERE id = 'G1'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/recursive-ctes#create-recursive-cte) help you?